# I am trying to assign a number to each character

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Recursion
{
    //variables to hold string values
    public static String s1 = new String(new char[10]);
    public static String s2 = new String(new char[10]);
    public static String s3 = new String(new char[11]);
    public static String charSet = new String(new char[11]);
    //variables to hold number values
    public static int numberOne;
    public static int numberTwo;
    public static int numberThree;
    public static int maxCharCount;
    public static int[] numberSet = new int[10];
    //function which generates a number
    public static void checkForEquality()
    {
        numberOne = numberTwo = numberThree = 0;
        int i;
        int j;
        for (i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < maxCharCount; j++)
            {
                if (s1.charAt(i) == charSet.charAt(j))
                {
                    if (i == 0 && numberSet[j] == 0)
                    return;
                    //generate the number
                    numberOne = (numberOne * 10) + numberSet[j];
                }
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < maxCharCount; j++)
            {
                if (s2.charAt(i) == charSet.charAt(j))
                {
                    if (i == 0 && numberSet[j] == 0)
                    return;
                    //generate number
                    numberTwo = (numberTwo * 10) + numberSet[j];
                }
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < s3.length(); i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < maxCharCount; j++)
            {
                if (s3.charAt(i) == charSet.charAt(j))
                {
                    if (i == 0 && numberSet[j] == 0)
                    return;
                    //generate the number
                    numberThree = (numberThree * 10) + numberSet[j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static void display(){
        if (numberOne + numberTwo == numberThree) {
            //display the output
            int i=0;
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print(" Summation Puzzle solved. ");
            System.out.print("n");
            System.out.print(s1);
            System.out.print("<==>");
            System.out.print(numberOne);
            System.out.print("n");
            System.out.print(s2);
            System.out.print("<==>");
            System.out.print(numberTwo);
            System.out.print("n");
            System.out.print(s3);
            System.out.print("<==>");
            System.out.print(numberThree);
            System.out.print("n");
            //loop to show the result
            for (i = 0; i < maxCharCount; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(charSet.charAt(i));
                System.out.print("<==>");
                System.out.print(numberSet[i]);
                System.out.print("n");
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    //recursive function which will call itself
    public static void Combinations(int indexCounter, int[] availableSet)
    {
        int i;
        if (indexCounter != 0)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                numberSet[indexCounter] = i;
                if (availableSet[i] == 1)
                {
                    availableSet[i] = 0;
                    Combinations(indexCounter + 1, availableSet);
                    availableSet[i] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if (indexCounter == maxCharCount)
        checkForEquality();
    }
    public static void createCharSet()
    {
        int i;
        int setIndex;
        int present;
        int j;
        setIndex = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++)
        {
            present = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < setIndex; j++)
            {
                if (s1.charAt(i) == charSet.charAt(j))
                {
                    present = 1;
                }
            }
            if (present == 0)
            {
                charSet = StringFunctions.changeCharacter(charSet, setIndex++, s1.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++)
        {
            present = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < setIndex; j++)
            {
                if (s2.charAt(i) == charSet.charAt(j))
                {
                    present = 1;
                }
            }
            if (present == 0)
            {
                charSet = StringFunctions.changeCharacter(charSet, setIndex++, s2.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < s3.length(); i++)
        {
            present = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < setIndex; j++)
            {
                if (s3.charAt(i) == charSet.charAt(j))
                {
                    present = 1;
                }
            }
            if (present == 0)
            {
                charSet = StringFunctions.changeCharacter(charSet, setIndex++, s3.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        maxCharCount = setIndex;
    }
    public static void calculateSummation()
    {
        int loop;
        if (maxCharCount > 10)
        {
            System.out.print("Please check the input again");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            int[] avaliableSet = new int[10];
            for (loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++)
            {
                avaliableSet[loop] = 1;
            }
            Combinations(0, avaliableSet);
        }
    }
    //main method
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the first String :");
        s1 = scan.next();
        System.out.print("Enter the second String :");
        s2 = scan.next();
        System.out.print("Enter the thirsd String :");
        s3 = scan.next();
        createCharSet();
        System.out.print(" result of your 3 three strings = ");
        System.out.print(charSet);
        calculateSummation();
        checkForEquality();
        display();
    }
}
```

Every time I run the program it just assigns 0 to each value. I want to be able to assign a value from 1-10 to each non numeric character. 
can someone help me out.?

it should look something like this 
[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyJhl.png)

Comment: a) That's a lot of code, try to create a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) b) if you want people to take time to help you, the least you could do is format it so it's easy to follow.

Comment: Please be more descriptive. What is "to each value", which value? Assign "1-10 to each non numeric character" what do you mean? Please trim down your code to the part that is relevant, and then we can help you more. Help us help you.

Comment: @JamesWierzba I wanted it how you see the picture attached. sorry for the poor description.

Comment: Is it just me, or reading code with brackets on the line after the declaration is painfull?

Comment: @dambros I feel the exact opposite, that way looks symmetrical to me.

Comment: @JamesWierzba I guess that is your C background talking :D

Comment: @dambros You know I actually started with Java but when I started C developing I saw the light

Answer (score 0):

First off, you may find debugging easier if you properly format your code. I remember you posting last night where you experienced similar issues resulting from syntax. You may find that your code is easier to read if you format it like this:

```
//function which generates a number
public static void checkForEquality(){
    numberOne = numberTwo = numberThree = 0;
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++){
        for (j = 0; j < maxCharCount; j++){
            if (s1.charAt(i) == charSet.charAt(j)){
                if (i == 0 && numberSet[j] == 0)
                    return;

               //generate the number   
                numberOne = (numberOne * 10) + numberSet[j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++){
        for (j = 0; j < maxCharCount; j++){
            if (s2.charAt(i) == charSet.charAt(j)){
                if (i == 0 && numberSet[j] == 0)
                    return;

               //generate number  
               numberTwo = (numberTwo * 10) + numberSet[j];
            }
        }
    }
```

Take a look at just this portion of your code and see if it still properly follows your algorithm. You may find an error which you could've located yourself with properly formatted code. If you take a look at a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36461487/2869332) of yours (which I answered) you'll find a helpful link that guides you to writing better code.

Also, I didn't try to compile this in my own IDE, but you should take a look at [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/mars2). A lot of the small errors you're getting could be located automatically by Eclipse.